# How to pass a parameter of byte array?

Tags: python, asmx, suds

I am using suds-jurko-0.6 to call an ASMX web service.

One of the parameters of a web method I am calling is of type byte array. The WSDL says the parameter is:

```
<data>base64Binary</data>
```

When I pass in a base 64 encoded value, say, `b'xyz'`, the actual data passed is:

```
<data>b&apos;xyz&apoos;</data>
```

It seems the `b` and quotation marks are also passed as part of the parameter value!

What transformation is needed to pass the byte array value correctly?

PS: I am using Python 3.4.

Comment: `.decode()` or even  `.decode(encoding)` converts a python bytearray to a string.

Comment: Thanks.  `.decode()` was what I was looking for - converting bytes to strings.  It works.